# Wpf.Webview2.CoreWebview2.get returned null. Object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, webview

I am trying to create a sample desktop wpf application with an html file added to it. I am using webview2.

Here is my markup:

```
<Wpf:WebView2 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="webContainer" />
```

and my code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string url1 = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\site\\index1.html";
    webContainer.CoreWebView2.Navigate(url1);
}
```

I am getting the following error on the line `Navigate()`

> Exception User-Unhandled
> System.NullReferenceException :Object reference not set to instance of an object.

```
 `Wpf.Webview2.CoreWebview2.get` returned null.
```

Can anyone help me identify the mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Navigate() keeps sending null exception but using Source() solved the exception.             
webContainer.Source=(uri1); solved it. also changed Name in XAML to x:Name

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution to correct Navigate() usage but switching to Source() solved the problem.Here is my solution

<Wpf:WebView2 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="webContainer" />

I also changed Name to x:Name

```
 public MainWindow()
  {    
 InitializeComponent();

Uri url1 = new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\site\\index1.html");
webContainer.Source = url1;
 }
```

Hope this helps anyone having the same issue

Comment: Hi, @beginner854. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.